# How to deploy Dash App with huge data sizes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, web-deployment, plotly-dash

I have been doing a Data Science project with ***Python*** and ***Sklearn*** and at this phase I would like to create a cloud-base visualization using the data and model I trained for my stakeholder. I have already finished the dash code and runs perfectly locally:

**My data size:** around 1 GB pickled file

**My model size:** around 4 GB pickled random forest model

I would need to use pandas to read in data and model to make predictions, then dash to make visualizations. When I deployed it locally I checked from my activity monitor and it's **consuming up to 18GB of RAM.**

Now the question is, how can I easily deploy it on cloud services. I noticed that Google App Engine provides up to 2GB RAM, it seems to me that Cloud Apps generally don't need that much of memories. Does anyone have any idea or experiences on how to manage cloud app deployment with huge data/model size?

Comment: Are you interested in deploying a web service or to having compute resources for your predictions and visualizations? If it is the second, I suggest you to take a look at [Google colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb)

Comment: Otherwise, I recommend using compute engine because you can have an instance as big as you need [n1-standard](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#highcpu) up to 86.4 GB RAM and [n2-standard](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n2_standard_machine_types) up to 320GB RAM.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://serverfault.com/q/1000834/321698

Comment: @Juancki I have done the computing part with GCE and I would like to deploy a web service which gives out real-time predictions using trained model. So first one I believe. Is there a way you can deploy web service from a GCE?

Comment: The idea is to create a GCE instance with the [desired settings](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux). Remember to accept HTTP(S) traffic. Then you connect to SSH and install the libraries and code. Finally run your service.

Comment: @Juancki that was very helpful! Thank you!